# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider (app.js seems to be defined correctly)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am dealing with that unknown provider issue, but have checked the other threads and applied those solutions to no avail. I want to get a service called 'MockSvc' to be injected into a controller without that error.  Any advice helps.

app.js:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';
    console.log('enter app.js....');
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

})();
```

service:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.factory('MockSvc', MockSvc);


    console.log('enter MockSvc...');

    function MockSvc(){

        var service = {

            };

            initialize();

            return service;

            function initialize() {

                console.log('enter MockSvc function init...');
            };


    }

})();
```

contoller:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);

    app.controller('PONumSearch2', PONumSearch);

    PONumSearch.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', '$location', '$window','MockSvc'];


    function PONumSearch($scope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore, $location, $window,MockSvc){ 

//controller logic would be below....

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller you do not have to inject the dependencies,If you inject dependencies, it will be considered as a new module and it is instantiated again.

Change

From

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
```

To

```
  var app = angular.module('app');
```

Inject **`ngCookies`** to your Main Module,

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngCookies']);
```